# Creating a C server

Tags: c, server, ipv4

I'm creating a C server. It does nothing but displaying a message saying the connection was established correctly for the moment:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "utils.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fd, fd_conn, result;
    struct sockaddr_in sock;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    exit_if(fd == -1, "socket");

    sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sock.sin_port = htons(7000);
    bzero(&(sock.sin_zero),8); // 0 en el resto de la estructura

    result = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    exit_if(result == -1, "bind");

    result = listen(fd, 5);
    exit_if(result == -1, "listen");

    fd_conn = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
    exit_if(fd_conn == -1, "accept");

    printf("Connection established\n");

    close(fd_conn);
    close(fd);
}
```

Apparently, when executed, it waits for incoming connections but when testing with telnet:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 7000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: Maybe there is a firewall (on localhost?) Check with `netstat -ln` if your server is actually is listening.

Comment: no, it's not listening...

Comment: There's something wrong with the bzero line I think. It aborts for me at exit_if "bind". If I replace the bzero with `memset(&sock, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));` before you start setting `sock.sin_*` then it works for me. I did have to add more header files, though, and make up exit_if (you haven't shown us utils.h) - try compiling with `-Wall` (or equivalent for your compiler) and make sure there are no warnings.

Comment: It does listen. After fixing trivial misstakes, like the above one.

Comment: @Rup The memset() is indeed in the wrong place. Strange enough, it seems to work (uninitialize being zero?) [I've added it to my answer, TNX]

Comment: @wildplasser I was just being lazy: I couldn’t remember the structure well enough to know if cleaning sin_zero was all you needed so seemed easier to clear the lot. You’re right sizeof sock is better / nicer syntax - my C is a bit rusty.

Comment: Me neither. Just zeroing the complete smart union before usage is easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your (trivial) errors:

---

```
#include <stdio.h> // for fprintf
#include <string.h> // for memset
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// #include "utils.h"
#define exit_if(a,b) if(a) {fprintf(stderr, b);}  else

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fd, fd_conn, result;
    struct sockaddr_in sock;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    exit_if(fd == -1, "socket");

    memset(&sock,0, sizeof sock); // <-- zero the complete struct.

    sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sock.sin_port = htons(7000);
    memset(&sock.sin_zero,0, sizeof sock.sin_zero); // <<-- not needed anymore

    result = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    exit_if(result == -1, "bind");

    result = listen(fd, 5);
    exit_if(result == -1, "listen");

    fd_conn = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);
    exit_if(fd_conn == -1, "accept");

    printf("Connection established\n");

    close(fd_conn);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```